# Why does the leftmost bar in an Altair Bar Chart not respect the selection brush location?

Tags: python, altair, streamlit

I created a simple bar chart based off of synthetic data, generated within the code below (generate_dataframe). The image has a top chart with the data and a lower chart that allows me to drag a selection along the horizontal axis. There appears to be an error: the leftmost bar is not affected by the motion of my selection in the lower plot. I use streamlit to display the plot. Here is an image of what is happening. I list the code below the image. Thanks for any advice.

[Image produced when running the code, enhanced to illustrate the issue described above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQNa9.jpg)

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy.random as random

def generate_dataframe():
    nrows = 400
    name = [ 'n' + str(i) for i in range(300) ]
    names = random.choice(name, nrows)

    centrality = random.rand(nrows)
    multiplier = random.choice([.3, 1., 300.], nrows)
    centrality *= multiplier
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x':names, 'y':centrality})
    return df

df = generate_dataframe()
#----------------------------------

brush = alt.selection(type="interval", encodings=['x'])
axis = alt.Axis(labels=False)

base = alt.Chart(df, title="Base view").mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('x:N', axis=axis),
    y='y:Q'
).add_selection(
    brush
).properties(
    width=850,
    height=50
)

zoomed = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('x:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=brush), axis=axis),
    y='y:Q'
).properties(
    width=850,
    height=400
)

chart = zoomed & base
st.altair_chart(chart)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Binding an interval selection to a scale's domain is currently not supported for ordinal and nominal domains.](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5340) A workaround is to use `.transform_filter()` instead, so change your code to this and you will no longer see the stacked bar to the left:

```
zoomed = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('x:N', axis=axis),
    y='y:Q'
).properties(
    width=850,
    height=400
).transform_filter(
    brush
)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Very elegant solution.

Comment: @GordonErlebacher You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the question as solved with the checkmark to the left.